# Escape regular expression reserved characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

Anyone know how to escape reserved regex's characters from a NSString?

I think these are the special characters that I must escape

```
. ^ $ * + - ? ( ) [ ] { } \ |
```

Currently I'm using this to escape all characters:

```
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"{" withString:@"\\{"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"}" withString:@"\\}"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"?" withString:@"\\?"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"+" withString:@"\\+"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"[" withString:@"\\["];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"(" withString:@"\\("];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @")" withString:@"\\)"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"^" withString:@"\\^"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"$" withString:@"\\$"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"|" withString:@"\\|"];
    regex = [regex stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"/" withString:@"\\/"];
```

but that's too expensive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, for those who want a simple way to do this you can check `NSRegularExpression` class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW32)

There you'll find some methods to do this, one of them is:

```
+ escapedTemplateForString:
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 3/4** use:

```
let escapedStr = NSRegularExpression.escapedPattern(for: myString)
```

**Result:**

```
myString = "Hello (world)"
escapedStr = "Hello \\(world\\)"
```

Works perfectly!